# Exclude urls from content scripts injection

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude urls from content scripts injection.

The code for testing purposes is as follows:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "exclude_globs": ["*"],
    "js" : ["jquery.min.js", "markdown.js", "main.js"],
    "css" : ["main.css"],
    "matches": [ "file:///*.md", "file:///*.markdown", "*://*/*.md", "*://*/*.markdown"]
}
```

This seems to prevent javascript injection but stylesheets get injected anyways.

I've been reading about some **exclude_globs** and **exlude_matches** bugs so I'm starting to think that this in fact is some kind of bug.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.